# How to enable voice button on android version of GoldenDict?

Tags: dictionary

Android version of Goldendict has a 'say' button that should play the pronunciation of the current word. However it's disable for me. How should I enable it? I guess I should copy sound files to a specific folder. What is its path?

Comment: Have you tried [their support](http://goldendict.mobi/support.php) or [FAQ](http://goldendict.mobi/faq.php)? Oh, forget that (sorry), full of spam. But checking their [Github issues](https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/issues) / open a new one would be an option.

Comment: I just think your chances might be better there ;) Good luck!